# How to reset Amazon Sagemaker Lab (delete all environments and local data - start fresh)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am using SageMaker it to test out some python code, and trial ML tasks. This requires me to install many python packages. I ran into package compatibility issues, overloaded the system with too many LLM models (take up too much space) and would simply like to start from scratch.

How do I simply reset the data which Sagemaker has (delete the VM and start over?)

I've looked for this option, but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: To do a 'hard reset' you can delete your account and request a new one with the same email.

Comment: Not ideal, but truthfully I do not even see an option to delete the account.

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative way:

Switch to base conda environment:
`conda activate base`

List all conda environments available in your account:
`conda list envs`

Delete all the conda environments except environment named 'base':
`conda remove -n "env_name" --all`

Delete all sub-directories from user folder:
`rm -rf /home/studio-lab-user/*`

Restart project/runtime.
Go to project page, stop instance and restart.

Comment: does this work? I'm in the same situation and pytorch drivers are no more compatible with CUDA 11.4, kind of stuck.